# How do I delay an event in xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am surprised I can't find this answer but for some reason can't find it for Xcode.

In my app I have an IBAction buttonPressed and it adds coins to my "coins" variable and displays it in a UILabel. I would like to make it so when the user presses the button it does not add the coins or display it in the UILabel for about 30 seconds. Is there a simple way to do this? I'm pretty new, so please explain in simple steps if possible. Thank You :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's very easy, just use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:. You would put it in your IBAction code like this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *) sender {
[self performSelector:@selector(addCoins) withObject:nil afterDelay:30];
}

-(void)addCoins {
//put whatever code you want to happen after the 30 seconds
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help that looks pretty straight forward. Right now I have declared and IBAction in my .h and then I have it in my .m with the code under it. Do I just put all your code in the .m and keep my declared action in the .h? Sorry but I really am new! :p

Comment: @Herbie999, you don't need to change anything in the .h file. In the .m, you can just move any code you have in the IBAction now, into the addCoins method.

Comment: Where I'm confused is that I have an IBAction buttonPressed in my .m do I get rid of that and replace it with the IBAction you showed. When I do it doesn't connect to my button. Sorry I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes, replace the code in it with what I showed. You might have to reconnect it in IB if you've made changes.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I just wasn't using the (UIButton * sender piece, but I took that out and it still works. Thank you for the help that was awesome :)